# Spark heapspace error while running Python program

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, heap-memory

When I running Python code in Spark using

```
spark-submit --master local --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1 \
--driver-memory 8G --executor-memory 7G
```

I get this error

> 17/02/28 18:59:25 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for /usr/local/bin/python2.7 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I get the same error when using

```
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024M
```

I have 32 GB of RAM and Java options are 4 GB.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please share stack trace of exception

Comment: Are you running this on you personal system or on cluster ? what is the volume of data.

Comment: Volume of data is 23MB and stack trace of exception is below.

Comment: 17/02/28 18:59:25 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for /usr/local/bin/python2.7
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: I was running in the cluster even I have tried in local as well but not workable in that too

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Would you mind sharing your code? (even if its still failing)